# Upper unit disc of $l^2(\mathbb {N})$ in $l^1(\mathbb {N})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis

While studying for an upcoming FA exam we stumbled over the following problem:
Given
$$\mathcal{A}= \{ x \in l^2(\mathbb{N}): x_i \geq 0 \text{ for all } i\in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } \sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i = 1\}$$
(i) Decicide (with proof) if $\mathcal{A}$ is precompact
(ii) Determine $\overline{\mathcal{A}}$

We did a counterexample for (i) and managed to prove that
$$\{ x \in l^2(\mathbb{N}): x_i \geq 0 \text{ for all } i\in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } \sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i \leq 1\} \subset \overline{\mathcal{A}}$$
By constructing
$$\{y_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\subset A, y_j=(\underbrace{\frac{1}{j},..,\frac{1}{j}}_{\text{j times}},0,0,...)$$
It follows by construction that $||y_n||_{l^2} = \frac{1}{n}\to 0$
If $z \in l^2 \text{ with } z_i \geq 0 \text{ for all } i\in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } ||z||_{l^1} = \alpha ,\ 0<\alpha<1 $
we consider $\widetilde{z_n} = z + (1-\alpha)y_n$
Again by construction this sequence of sequences is in $\mathcal{A}$ and converges to $z$ in $l^2$.
However we did not manage to show that the set defined above is closed i.e. that it is impossible to find a sequence in $\mathcal{A}$ that converges to some sequence with $l^1$-Norm $>1$.
So my question is: Is the set defined above already the closure and if yes, how can we argue that the set defined above is already closed?

Comment: It is not closed. For a sequence in this set which converges to $0$ look at $(\frac 1 n, \frac 1 n,,...,\frac 1 n,,0,0,...)$. The closure is the set of all non-negative sequences in $\ell^{2}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes, we found the same sequence that converges to 0. However we did not manage to construct a sequence in in $\mathcal{A}$ that converges to a sequence with a $||y||_{\ell^1}>1$. Do you have a hint maybe?

Comment: Hint: Fatou's Lemma!